# Can you derive a new variable from two other variables in flutter

Tags: python, java, flutter, dart, web

I'm a bit new to flutter so please bare with me
for example

```
company_name ='MarioInc"
isChecked = false
```

string concatenation is something I get (I think) and below is an example
done with `'${company_name}.${isChecked}'` which should give you `MarioInc.false` as a string. However I want it to return a new variable called `company_name.isChecked` not as a string. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with creating a class about it

```
class CompanyStatus{
    String company_name;
    bool isChecked;
}
```

And when you create an object from that class, you should be able to retrieve the name and check status of that object

Example

```
var company = CompanyStatus(company_name : "Example Company", isChecked: false);

print(company.isChecked);
print(company.company_name);
```